# Sonarqube quality gate condition using 'Severity'

Tags: security, sonarqube

I would like to setup a quality gate that checks:

- No Vulnerabilities
- No Bugs with severity >= Major

Can I, and if so how, add that severity into the condition?

Regards!

Comment: Did you try changing the quality gate in that way?

Comment: Yes I did but I can not find anything related to severity and I do not want a quality gate condition on minor minor codesmells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely on the Maintainability Rating, the Reliability Rating and the Security Rating similar to what's done on [sonarcloud.io](https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/default/quality_gates/show/9). You may want to rely on New Code instead of the overall rating to take profit of the [leak concept](https://blog.sonarsource.com/water-leak-changes-the-game-for-technical-debt-management/).

Comment: ths is what I am doing at the moment. But still it would be good if I can make this more granular. Thank you for your answer